# GKTurnBasedMatch saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData returning an error on every other call

Tags: ios, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

The player takes multiple actions before completing a turn.  After each action, I call saveCurrentTurnWIthMatchData, with the match data updated.

```
[gameMatch saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData: matchData completionHandler: ^(NSError *error){
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error updating match = %@",error);
             }
     }];
```

On every other call I get "Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5002 "status = 5002, Unexpected game state version expectedGameStateVersion='null'"

The GKTurnBasedMatch.state = 3 (GKTurnBasedMatchStatusMatching) in every call. I'm not changing this, I just check before the call. I have no idea if this is relevant.

Any suggestion what to try?

Answer (score 0):

the "Unexpected game state version" error happens irregularly and is hard to reproduce -- although i can often reproduce it by calling `saveCurrentTurn` several times in rapid succession. it would be useful to have clarity from Apple on this since it *appears* to be server side (but i'm not sure). i wrote a unit test that does stress testing on `GKTurnBasedMatch.saveCurrentTurn`. it fails irregularly but often up to 20% of the time.

i have no full solution only a partial one. to partially mitigate the problem, you can wrap your `saveCurrentTurn` calls in a task queue, that way they wait for the previous one to finish. not a solution, but helps.

```
let dqt:DispatchQueueTask = {
    gkTurnBasedMatch.saveCurrentTurn(withMatch:payload) { error in
        //handle error
        TaskQueue.completion() //step to next task
    }
}
TaskQueue.add(task:dqt)
```

and here is the TaskQueue class i use

```
import Foundation

/*
 Uses the DispatchQueue to execute network commands in series
 useful for server commands like GKTurnBasedMatch.saveCurrentTurn(...)

 Usage:
     let doSomethingThatTakesTime:DispatchQueueTask = {
         ...
         TaskQueue.completion()
     }
 
     TaskQueue.add(task: doSomethingThatTakesTime)
 */

typealias DispatchQueueTask = () -> ()
let DispatchQueue_serial = DispatchQueue(label: "org.my.queue.serial")

class TaskQueue {
    static var isRunning:Bool = false
    static var tasks:[DispatchQueueTask] = []
    
    static func add(task:@escaping DispatchQueueTask) {
        tasks.append(task)
        run()
    }
        
    static func run() {
        guard !isRunning else { return }
        guard tasks.count > 0 else { return }
        let task = tasks.removeFirst()
        DispatchQueue_serial.async {
            TaskQueue.isRunning = true
            task()
        }
    }

    static func completion() {
        TaskQueue.isRunning = false
        TaskQueue.run()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  It is very helpful to know that this really is an "intermittent" issue.  I found that endTurn addresses the issue as well.  I also found that if I just re-call the endpoint after receiving the error (I wait for 1 second before doing so, but don't know if that is relevant), the save happens.  So, I took the easiest route, and just tried again....  Thanks very much